# Why does export not seems to affect child shells?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

if I have

```
$ x='This is a String'
$ export x

$ xterm &
[3] 14089
```

The child process doesn't seem to respond to

```
$echo $x
$
```

**Update:**  The FIRST time  I export the variable it seems to span a process? -

```
$ export xb
[1]+  Done                    xterm
durrantm.../durrantm$ export xb
durrantm.../durrantm$ 
# Note second export didn't say anything.
```

Comment: Do you mean `echo $x`?

Comment: (1) Did you test the exact commands shown in your question? (2) Anything interesting (non-default) about your environment, e.g., are you using `screen` as a shell or something?

Comment: I checked again and verified issue with other vafriable names.  I use tmux (terminal multiplexor), maybe that's it.

Comment: Do you mean that you attach an already existing tmux session in that xterm that you spawn from the shell you exported `x` in?

Comment: nope, new session only after export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not export the parent's environment into any of it's children, once the child has been forked. The children are forked shells which when spun up get a copy of the parent's environment at that moment. From that point forward they're on their own.

In your case you're setting the variables prior to forking so you should see any variables that were set in any children. However it looks like you're running into a typo. Try `echo $x`.

#### Example

In parent shell:

```
$ x='This is a String'
$ export x
$ xterm &
[1] 28578
```

In xterm:

```
$ echo $x
This is a String
```

#### Variable getting reset by login files?

In some rare cases you may have a stray `set` or `unset` which would obliterate the parent's environment variable from being passed cleanly to any children. You can check this as follows:

```
# login shell
$ bash -c -l 'echo $x'
This is a String

# interactive shell
$ bash -c -i 'echo $x'
This is a String
```

You can also use Bash's `-x` switch so that the above output is more verbose.

```
$ bash -x -c -i 'echo $x'
```

Comment: As I understand the OP question, the `export` is done before launching the new shell and in the same terminal.

Comment: @lgeorget - see updates

Comment: Yes, I am doing the export first and the echo $x ('scuse the missing $ initially) but not getting the expected output.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - did you retry with the missing `$`? I just did this exact thing and it worked fine.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - is the variable being unset by your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I suggest you try with a variable name more distinctive than `x`. Far too likely for a short variable like `x` or `i` to be overwritten/unset by a .bashrc or similar. My random string generator says to try `bROmL7AN='This is a string'` (etc).

Comment: @derobert - nice!

Comment: Good idea.  Yes, I tried xblog and then display of $xblog and same issue.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - this is one of those moments where we all know it's going to be something stupid 8-). What did the `bash -x -c -i ....` show? Can you provide it's output?

Comment: Output is massive, over 20 pages, many hundreds of lines.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant - yeah that's usually the case.